# How to undo misclicks while drawing a polygon or line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, polygon-creation, polyline-creation

While drawing some large polygons or long continuous lines in QGIS and I tend to misclick.

Then everytime I misclick, I don't find a way to undo that last point (or several of the last points) and start re-drawing the polygon or line all over again.

Answer (score 24):

The latest inserted vertices can be removed one by one by hitting either Del or BackSpace keys.

It really seems to be undocumented in the current QGIS 2.2 manual at http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html. It would belong to the Adding Features section which tells at the moment only how to add vertices and finish digitizing.

> For lines and polygons, keep on left-clicking for each additional
>   point you wish to capture. When you have finished adding points,
>   right-click anywhere on the map area to confirm you have finished
>   entering the geometry of that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Delete/Backspace did not work for me, but Control+Z did.

Answer (score 1):

To undo the last step while drawing a polygon in QGIS use **DELETE** or **BACKSPACE** once.

if needed to go several steps back, press either **DELETE** or **BACKSPACE** the required number of times till you undone number of steps you required.

Note - do not press **CTRL + Z** because it will undo the last finalised edit or drawing have been created even off view sometimes this can delete critical information or drawings in the drawing which cannot be recovered.